# Search SVN File's History for Particular String

Tags: svn, version-control

This is probably basic, but I have not been with SVN for long and am wondering how to do it.

Suppose I have a line of text, say, `Hello world!`

I would like to search a particular file's history in my SVN repository to see when that line disappeared from there.

What is an efficient way to do that? A command line operation should work. However, something via ViewVC is also an option.

Much appreciated.